# How to solve system of Differential Equations with 1 independent and 3 dependent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, general-relativity

How can one solve this set of three differential equations in one independent variable "t" and three dependent variables A, B and F, which are functions of only t?
$$
\frac{F(t) B''(t)+B'(t) F'(t)+B(t) F''(t)}{B(t) F(t)}=0, \\
\frac{F(t) A''(t)+A'(t) F'(t)+A(t) F''(t)}{A(t) F(t)}=0, \\
\frac{A'(t)}{A(t)}+\frac{B'(t)}{B(t)}=0
$$
By the way, what are such systems called?
I came across this set as Einstein's Equations for a certain space-time in General Relativity.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here,  but at first glance,  you could simplify the first two equations by ignoring the denominators :)

Comment: where is it origin ?

Comment: I don't know whether it'll help or not but terms can be simplified to $$\frac{B''(t)}{B(t)}+\frac{F''(t)}{F(t)}+\frac{B'(t)F'(t)}{B(t)F(t)}=0 ------- (1)$$

$$\frac{A''(t)}{A(t)}+\frac{F''(t)}{F(t)}+\frac{A'(t)F'(t)}{A(t)F(t)}=0 ------ (2)$$

From (1), (2) and your third equation,

$$2\frac{F''(t)}{F(t)}+\frac{B'(t)F'(t)+A'(t)F'(t)}{A(t)F(t)}=0$$

Comment: from 3rd :A'B+B'A=0  ---> SO (AB)'=0 ---> SO  AB(t)=CONST     (may help)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$from-3rd-equation\\\frac{A'}{A}+\frac{B'}{B}=0\\\frac{A'B+AB'}{AB}=0\\(AB)'=0 \\AB=constant \\AB=c\\Put\\B=\frac{c}{A}\\B'=\frac{-cA'}{A^2}\\B''=\frac{-cA''A^2 +2AA'cA'}{A^4}=\frac{-c(A''A +2A'A')}{A^3}\\now\\put \\in- 1st-equation\\then- you - have -two-equation- with- 
A ,F $$